# Erro em no Enable-Migrations em EF5 com MySql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, migrations

Estou com um problema em meu projeto, ao tentar habilitar o Migrations no projeto ele gera uma exceção conforme abaixo:

```
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data.Entity.EF5, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'MySql.Data.Entity.EF5, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory.get_MySqlDbProviderServicesInstance()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory.System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderServices(DbProviderFactory factory)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_CodeFirstModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
```

Estou utilizando VS2015, EF5 e MySql 6.7.9.0, ele até adiciona o arquivo de configuração do Migration mas apresenta este erro e não permite criar migrações ou dar update no banco.

Comment: Passei por alguns problemas para configurar o EF com MySQL a pouco tempo. Apesar de não ter visto esse mesmo erro que vc está tendo, esse link me ajudou muito à implementar o que precisava. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html Espero ter ajudado.